# property 'pathname' undefined in React Routers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router

I am following a tutorial on youtube on building a landing page, but I got stuck on this phase.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined at new Router

Here is the code:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The tutorial I am following is using react-router version **5.0.1**

Also here is my App.js code that is being used in index.js:

```
import "./css/App.css";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Main from "./pages";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Added Main.js code**

```
import Header from "../components/Header";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

I tried searching for changes but was unsuccessful in finding a solution that worked.

Comment: Add some code which includes the `pathname` would be help

Comment: Your code is working [fine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rahjd4). Can you add the snippet where you have used `pathname`?

Comment: Added main.js code,which is being refrenced by App.js

Comment: We can't find the `pathname` in your code.

Comment: Surely in the console where you see the error it informs you what component it occurs in, accompanied by line number. Please include *that* component's code. `Main` will receive Route props, but any children of `Main` will not automatically receive them.